# Replacing the number with the number of spaces

Tags: java

I have a String:

```
String example = "AA5DD2EE3MM";
```

I want to replace the number with the number of spaces. Example:

```
String example = "AA     DD  EE   MM"
```

If the String would be

```
String anotherExample = "a3ee"
```

It should turn into:

```
String anotherExample = "a   ee"
```

I want to do it for any string. Not only for the examples above.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Start with an empty string called `result`. Loop through each character in the `example` string. Check to see if the character is a number. If it is not a number, append the character to the `result`. If it is a number, run a new loop that appends that many spaces to `result`. That should be a start for atleast handling numbers from 0 to 9 that gets converted to spaces. Try to write some code, and come back with quuestions about that code.

Comment: Is ```A11A```  2 spaces or 11 spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split your input at digit and non digit chars as a stream, map digits to the corsponding number of spaces using `String.repeat`, collect to string using `Collectors.joining()`:

```
String input  = "AA5DD2EE3MM";
String regex  = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)";
String result = Pattern.compile(regex)
                        .splitAsStream(input)
                        .map(s -> s.matches("\\d+") ? " ".repeat(Integer.parseInt(s)) : s)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: I think you can just simplify your regex to `\d+`, but +1 for your tight approach.

Comment: Looks good. I like the concise approach!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this approach, which is simpler but also far less elegant:

```java
String example = "a4aa";
String newString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < example.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(example.charAt(i))) {
        for (int a = 0; a < Character.getNumericValue(example.charAt(i)); a++) {
            newString += " ";
        }
    } else {
        newString += example.charAt(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(newString);
```

Comment: Instead of `Integer.parseInt(String)` I would suggest `Character.getNumericValue(char)`, which you can use directly on the `char` instead of having to create another `String`. Also, consider removing all those empty lines from your code, which would improve readability by a lot.

Comment: @maloomeister That is definitely the better way, I have just changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pattern matcher approach:

```
String input = "AA5DD2EE3MM";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buffer,new String(new char[Integer.valueOf(m.group())]).replace("\0", " "));
}
m.appendTail(buffer);
System.out.println(buffer.toString());  // AA     DD  EE   MM
```

The idea here is to iterate the string, pausing at each digit match.  We replace each digit with space replicated the same number of times as the digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String replaceDigitsWithSpaces(String input) {
    String result = "";
    int len = input.length(), i =0;
    
    while( i < len) {
        
        if(Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i))) {
            result += input.charAt(i);
        }else if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {
            //generate number upto characters
            int k = 0, j = i;
            String temp = "";
            while(j < len) {
                if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(j))) {
                    temp += input.charAt(j);
                    j++;
                }else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            k = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            while(k != 0) {
                result+= " ";
                k--;
            }
            i = j;
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}

input:: "AA23BB1C11C8"<br>
output:: AA                       BB C           C        .
```

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` is more efficient for concatenation:

```
    public static String spaceIt(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Character.digit(c, 10); j++) {
                    sb.append(' ');
                }
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```